# How to debug a remote PHP script that is called by a third server

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I need to debug a PHP script on a remote server that I can not call from my web browser. Instead it is called by a third party server as a web hook.
Preferably I would like to make the webhook start a remote Xdebug session and step through the code in the NetBeans IDE that I am using.

I am using an SSH tunnel to connect the remote debugger to my development machine.

I can not use the GET/POST/COOKIE variable with the webhook so I have set `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` to make the debug session start nontheless.
I have added a couple of break points to my page and have it opened in the IDE Editor while I fire up the webhook call from the third server.

Still a debug session is not started. I know that the page is executed because I have added some logging commands to it.
Is it at all possible to do what I want? Thanks for any hints and comments!

When answering please note: I will not accept any answer that recommends logging to a file because that is what I am already doing. 
Thanks!

Here is the Xdebug section of my php.ini (and yes it is the correct php.ini file instance):

```
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Here is the Xdebug log of the session.

```
[21318] Log opened at 2019-04-01 19:50:38
[21318] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
[21318] I: Connected to client. :-)
[21318] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" 
    xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" 
    fileuri="file:///var/www/couchback/update.php" 
    language="PHP" 
    xdebug:language_version="7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.2" 
    protocol_version="1.0" 
    appid="21318" 
    idekey="netbeans-xdebug">
        <engine version="2.7.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine>
        <author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author>
        <url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url>
        <copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2019 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright>
    </init>
[21318]
[21318] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" re
ason="ok"></response>
[21318]
[21318] Log closed at 2019-04-01 19:50:40
```

The debug session is started but for some reason the IDE does not seem to take care. Probably that is because of the missing idekey in the uri? I have no means to add the idekey since the webhook originates from a third party. It might be an option to send the webhook to a proxy and forward the call with the idekey added to it. I will be happy to hear any other suggestions that are not as complicated.

Comment: Your config is set to have Xdebug connect to 127.0.0.1:9000. Is that port mapped via the SSH tunnel to port 9000 on your local machine? Also, you can use the property `xdebug.remote_log` to have Xdebug log details about its attempt to connect, which should make it easier to tell why the debug session isn't starting.

Comment: Thanks for that very helpful suggestion. Looking at the xdebug log already gave me an idea of what might cause the problem. I have edited my queston to include the log.

Comment: Change Xdebug port to be `9001` or some another one (in all paces, of course). As you can see from the Xdebug log, it has response. The service that replied on that connection is perfectly aware of Xdebug protocol. Right now you may be connecting to a php-fpm that uses the same TCP 9000 port by default ... and it is the exact reaction when xdebug tries to connect there (the response basically means: "end of session / go away").